# Mocha test.Timeout 2000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, testing, mocha.js

What I am doing wrong?I am trying to save phones to my db,but mocha says Timeout of 2000ms exceeded.
My phone schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const phoneSchema = new Schema({
    company: String,
    modelname: String,
    numbername: String,
    picture: String,
    price: String,
});

const Phone = mongoose.model('phone', phoneSchema);

module.exports = Phone;
```

and my test file:

```
    const mocha = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');
const Phone = require('../models/phone-model');


//describe tests
describe('Saving records', function(){
    //create tests
    it('Saves phone to the db',function(done){

        var phone1 = new Phone({
            company: "Samsung",
            modelname: "Galaxy",
            numbername: "S5",
            picture: "https://drop.ndtv.com/TECH/product_database/images/2252014124325AM_635_samsung_galaxy_s5.jpeg",
            price: "12500P"
        });

        phone1.save().then(function(){
            assert(phone1.isNew === false);
            done(); 
        });

    });

});
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here..it always works for me before this.
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Oauth\test\phone_test.js)

Comment: A simple explanation would be the `save()` not resolving. Try adding a `catch()`.

Comment: This is one of few reasons why returning a promise from a spec is a good idea and using `done` isn't.

Comment: Don't add a catch. Just return the promise from your `then`. If it rejects, the test will fail. No need for redundant failure handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments have said, you're only calling `done` if the promise from the `save` method resolves, meaning that your test will time out if your database sends an error response.

Since you're dealing with promises, try using mocha's [built-in promise support](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) instead of the `done` callback:

```
const mocha = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');
const Phone = require('../models/phone-model');

describe('Saving records', function(){
    // Note there is no `done` argument here
    it('Saves phone to the db',function(){

        var phone1 = new Phone({
            company: "Samsung",
            modelname: "Galaxy",
            numbername: "S5",
            picture: "https://drop.ndtv.com/TECH/product_database/images/2252014124325AM_635_samsung_galaxy_s5.jpeg",
            price: "12500P"
        });

        // Note returning the promise here...
        return phone1.save().then(function(){
            assert(phone1.isNew === false);
        });

    });

});
```

Let us know what you see after this. Hopefully you'll see an actual error message that will help you track down the problem. Your DB also very well could be taking longer than 2000ms to respond, though this is more likely.